# Angular delete with filter item

Tags: angular, filter

I have a little problem with delete item in angular, it's work, I can delete but When the item deleted I want that he recedes if all items

my compoennt :

```
  public allUsersNormal: User[];

  constructor(
    private _usersService: UsersService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsersNormal()
  }

  private getAllUsersNormal() {
    this._usersService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      return this.allUsersNormal = data
    })
  }

  public deletesUser(user: User) {
    return this._usersService.deleteUser(user).subscribe(() => {
      return this.allUsersNormal.filter(allUsers => {
        console.log(allUsers._id !== user._id)
        return allUsers._id !== user._id
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: I would advice you to not manually delete a user from your frontend. I'd rather get all users from the backend after deleting a user.

Also: Your problem here is that you cannot return anything in your `subscribe()` method, since that's async. But, you're manipulating your object anyway, so you should have the current state in `this.allUsersNormal`. You just cannot return them from your delete method.

Comment: You better use splice to remove from array

Comment: You don't understand my question, in my subscribe I have response of back with user's data (_id, name, age, email, ...) and in my (this.allUsersNormal) I have all users.When I try delete in database it's work, but I want then recede this user of allUsers